# Make the pattern from composition notebooks

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

This challenge was [xnor's idea](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5535/34638), taken from [Digital Trauma's challenge donation thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/secret-santas-sandbox).

---

Your challenge is to write a program that, as xnor put it, "procedurally generate[s] the splotchy black-and-white marbled pattern on the covers of composition notebooks":

[image: 1]]

Your program can either display it on the screen or save it in a file. The image should be at least 300 pixels in each dimension, and it should be different between runs of the program. Your program should not just load an external image and use that as its output; the image should be generated by your program.

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), and it will use xnor's criteria for voting:

- Similarity to the reference texture above.
- Simplicity of generation method.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to post another user's challenge straight out of the sandbox, although it has a highly voted critical comment. At the very least, you should repost it in the sandbox, addressing those concerns and getting some up-to-date feedback. I do think this is way too broad to work well as a pop-con and it's also too similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/43274/8478.

Comment: Lastly, I don't understand how it's possible to generate such an image *without* some form of noise. Whether I use a pre-made function to generate the noise, or port some Perlin noise code from elsewhere into my program doesn't really make a difference for a popcon since there is no incentive to keep the code short.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I understand your points, but I think this is different from that other challenge. This image is simpler than the pictures of the wall, and I think it's clearer what exactly the output should look like. I removed the part about external noise generators, because I agree with you and I think it was unclear.

Comment: For me there's 3 kinds of popcon. The worst is "do x in the most wacky way possible" which this clearly isn't  Then there's pure art, which we decided is off topic (though there's many old challenges of this type.) Finally there's the best type of popcon: image processing, which is always highly voted. The great thing is you often don't know how good an algorithm will look till you see the result. This for me is a mediocre example of the best type of popcon. It's v similar to linked challenge. But the image to emulate is clear - I don't see ambiguity in requirements as an issue. +1 (only just)

Comment: @MartinBüttner your first comment could give the impression KSFT stole this challenge from Xnor. But on investigation I understand Xnor gave it away.

Comment: @steveverrill that's not what I meant to imply. I'm saying even you post another user's challenge with their permission, you shouldn't just copy it straight from the sandbox to main. Usually there's a very good reason why the original author didn't do just that.

Comment: I don't understand how this could be both possibly too similar to another contest that isn't closed *and* too broad.

Answer (score 16):

## Mathematica

```
Blur[Binarize[Blur[RandomImage[1, {1000, 1000}, ImageSize -> Large], 6], .52]]
```

Quite simple. Creates a random grayscale image, blurs it, takes the pixels above a threshold, and blurs it again. It uses a couple of hand-tweaked values. The result:

[image]

Comment: This is really good! On first glance I thought you reposted the reference image.

Comment: @xnor I myself was surprised what a small amount of hand-tweaking could do.